# How do I resolve "'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'" in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to put a condition in code below. As you can see, I want to print the respective message for respective values of BMI.
I am having an error for <= or >+ used in the if and elif statements. Please tell me what to use in this case.

```
def bmi(w,h):
    print((w)/(h**2))

weight = float(input('Weight (kg): '))
height = float(input('Height (m): '))
b = bmi(weight,height)

if 18<b<25 :
    print('Your weight is normal.')
elif b<18:
    print('You are underweight.')
elif 25<b<29:
    print('You are overweight.')
elif b>29:
    print('You are obese.')
```

Output -

```
Weight (kg): 65
Height (m): 1.72
21.971335857220122
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Coding/Python Exercises/Ass5/Ass5.py", line 8, in <module>
    if 18<b<25 :
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Instead of returning `(w)/(h**2)` you are printing it and the function is returning None. Change print to return

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your function:

```
def bmi(w,h):
    print((w)/(h**2))
```

You don't return anything in this function and so, when you are calling it in the line `b = bmi(weight,height)`, you don't set `b` to be anything other than a None value. All you've done is print the `bmi` to the screen, but you haven't set `b` to a float value which is why you get the error (which is telling you you can't compare a float to a None using operators like `>`). You want to add a return statement so that your function actually returns something when called, like so:

```
def bmi(w,h):
    print((w)/(h**2))
    return w/h**2
```

Comment: I'd argue that the function shouldn't `print` anything at all. Good practice would be for the caller to do that if and when it's desired behavior.

Comment: "You don't return anything in this function and so, when you are calling it in the line b = bmi(weight,height), you don't set b to be anything other than a None value"
I have used `weight = float(input('Weight (kg): '))
height = float(input('Height (m): '))`
Isn't this assigning value to b ?

Comment: No, those lines assign value to the variables `weight` and `height` respectively. You don't try to assign a value to `b` until you get to the line `b=bmi(weight,height)`. That line says "set `b` to be the return value of the function `bmi` when called with the parameters `weight` and `height`". It so happens that the return value of `bmi` is `None` since you don't have a return statement in that function.